# How to make Unity pass a constructor parameter based on Web API request?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web API in a multi-tenant environnement.  Each tenant has their own database with an identical structure.  The tenant name is included in the URL as a sub-domain : http://{tenant}.mysite.com/api/doodad/action

I've written a message filter (DelegatingHandler) to pull out the tenant name and find the corresponding database.  I'm currently stashing this value in the request parameters.

Pretty much every controller action needs access a DbContext pointing to this database.  I'm not using a repository pattern.  I've created a second constructor on my DbContext that accepts the database name.

I'm using Unity to inject an instance of the DbContext in the ApiController.  How can I get Unity to call the second constructor on the DbContext passing in the value from the request parameter?

Comment: Use factort method registration. This way it is you who provide explicit factory method.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I think it should work...

You could create an action filter that would add the HttpRequestMessage to the current hierarchical container and then register your custom DbContext type with an InjectionFactory to pull out the HttpRequestMessage and get the DB name.

Here's some untested code...

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RegisterHttpRequestActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var container = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUnityContainer)) as IUnityContainer;
        container.RegisterInstance(actionContext.Request, new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

and the configuration...

```
IUnityContainer rootContainer = new UnityContainer();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(rootContainer);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new RegisterHttpRequestActionAttribute());

rootContainer.RegisterType<MyDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(container => 
    new MyDbContext(container.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>().Properties["TenantDB"] as string)));
```

(FYI, I reference the Unity.AspNet.WebApi NuGet package to get the UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver)